# How can I continue the test flow even if the element cant be located in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting the input data from the excel sheet, I iterate the rows by using for-loop.

If suppose the element is not found, then the flow stops. But I want to continue the flow by taking a screenshot at the page where it failed to move on next.

I tried by using below method:

```java
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
    if (ITestResult.FAILURE == result.getStatus()) {
        try {
            TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
            File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File("D:\\Screenshot" + result.getName() + ".png"));
            System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while taking screenshot " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I get the input from a separate class, so how can I continue the for-loop without interrupting the flow of the loop.

Hope I made it clear.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: inside the for you call tearDown method ?

Comment: Which element are we talking about? Also since they're probably related, please show the method including your _for-loop_ so we can see what you're doing. Most probably you can add a `try-catch` block and take a screenshot when the exception is thrown, but at this point we can only guess...

Comment: No, this method gets called on a failure case @ Leon

Comment: That's partially true: the TestNG framwork ensures that methods annotated with `@AfterMethod` are invoked after running each test method, no matter if they fail or succeed. **P.S.** you can use @username when replying to someone so they get notified.

Comment: @Morfic, this is about selenium webdriver elements.

Comment: so, my guess is something has to be done within this method, so that I can continue the for-loop @Morfic

Comment: Not really, the `@AfterMethod` gets executed after your test method where I assume your loop is. So like I said, probably you'll have to so something like @LeonBarkan suggested below. In short, for each loop, if an exception is thrown such as `ElementNotFoundException`, catch it, take a screenshot and continue. This can be further enhanced to keep track of any exception, and after the `for` decide whether the test can be considered successful or failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116571/discussion-between-prabhu-and-morfic).

Answer (score 0):

Try catch need to be inside the for loop and if its catches it will take a screenshot and continue to next element in the loop

```
for(...)
{
   try
   {
      //your code from excel
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      //if throwing exception take screenshot
   }
}
```

Comment: But, the selenium codes are in different method, I doubt if it will works

Comment: @Prabhu If you want your loop to continue, you need to catch the exceptions thrown within. Otherwise the looping will stop at the first exception throw, so you need to reconsider your test's architecture.

Comment: if the selenium is method that runs from for loop with the parameters from specific info from excel it will skip that one with error try to throw an exception from the selenium method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some code where the element may not exist and check to see if it exists. If it doesn't, then take a screenshot and continue the test. I don't have any of your code but here's a simple example that should give you the basic idea.

```
if (driver.findElements(locator).isEmpty())
{
    // element not found
    // take screenshot here
}

// continue script here
```

There's no need to add code to the `tearDown()` method.

Comment: Did you add your own locator? What code are you using? What error did it throw?